# Google Distances in R between two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, googleway

I have two data frames.  One has ~600 or so locations of people on a map, like so:

```
Names<-c("Mike","Ron","Joe")
Lat<-c(61.5,63.2,50.1)
Long<-c(-140.2,-139.2,-145.6)
df<-data.frame(Names,Lat,Long)
```

The other has locations those people might need to get to:

```
Places<-c("ClinicA","ClinicB","ClinicC")
Lat<-c(58.5,50.2,40.1)
Long<-c(-135.2,-133.2,-140.6)
df1<-data.frame(Places,Lat,Long)
```

I know that if I have an individual set of coordinates I can use googleway to get the distances in between like so:

```
df <- google_distance(origins = list(c("Melbourne Airport, Australia"),
                                 c("MCG, Melbourne, Australia"),
                                 c(-37.81659, 144.9841)),
                  destinations = c("Portsea, Melbourne, Australia"),
                  key = key)
```

My question is, I'd like to go through each individual person, calculate the distance to each of the locations of the places (i.e. return three different distances for each person), and then only keep the smallest distance for each.  The resulting data frame would hopefully be:

Rows of: Name, lat,long,NearestPlace,Distance to that place

I'm assuming it'd maybe be a "for" loop, but I'm kinda lost at this point.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are the Lat and Long values in `df` and `df1` legit?

Comment: Oh I just made those particular ones up (you're referring to the -135.2, -133.2?)  but they SHOULD work, even without the extra decimal places.  Is that what you meant? Oh, I guess 58 is too high.  But besides that, if you took like 30,-145

Comment: I don't believe the distance API works correctly with just random collections of Lat/Long

Comment: Yea I just saw that when I tried those numbers (wouldn't give me a distance if the location was in the middle of the ocean).  That being said, assuming we had real, on-land, locations (which we do), do you have any ideas of how I could write that code?  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like this has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48929667/2572423).

Comment: If you're only after the shortest distance (as the crow flies) there are much simpler methods for solving this which won't require loops or calls to Google's API. Otherwise, if you actually need the driving/walking/route distances then the answer linked by @JasonAizkalns might be what you're after

Comment: Actually SymbolixAU, that would definitely help!  The google API thing looks like it would take 100,000 searches, which at that volume I'd have to pay for.  Unfortunately I'm kinda lost as to which other methods I could use.  Could you point me in the right direction?