# Looping over dataframe with google way

Tags: r, loops, googleway

I am trying to replicate the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929667/convert-export-googleway-output-to-data-frame/48937052#48937052) but for google_places() instead of google_distance().

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: Latitude and Longitude.

I tried it like this:

```
set_key("my key number")

lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){
  google_places(location = c(df$Latitude, df$Longitude)),
                search_string = 'Coffee Shop',
                radius = 5000)
})
```

R returns:
Error in validateGeocodeLocation(location) :
location must be a vector of a pair of latitude and longitude coordinates

I tried different ways of looping, I change the dataframe to a list, also I tried putting the Latitude and Longitude in a single vector, but still I get the same error.

My df is 150 rows (that means 150 locations to go over). I just want the lists of the 20 places found in the radius around each location.

Comment: the first argument of your `lapply()` is `1:nrow(df)` (the row numbers). So the `x` that's passed into `function(x)` is a row number. So you need to use the row number `x` to select the row of your data.frame `df`. So you probably want to replace the `location` argument with `df[x, "Latitude"], df[x, "Longitude"]`

Comment: In the question you've linked this is done in the `origins[x, "V1"], origins[x,"V2"]` line

Comment: @tospig, thank you for helping. I tried what you said, but I get the same error.

Comment: can you edit your question with what you tried?